# Pull up resistor for 555 Timer IC

Tags: resistors, 555

https://makezine.com/projects/laser-tripwire-alarm/

I need help determining the pull up resistor needed for this circuit.

It uses a 555 Timer IC.

The resistor R1 acts as a pull-up resistor for pin 2. It helps to prevent false triggering from static electricity. But in many cases it can be left off without causing any problems.

[image]

Comment: Please add the schematic into your question. That way we don't have to follow a link to understand your question and it will still be relevant if the link dies.

Comment: What measurements have you made for light interruption on each pin?

Comment: Looking at the photos on the page you linked is quite clear that R1 has a value of 1k and R2 is 100 Ohm

Comment: Will include schematic next time. @Transistor

Comment: @Elmesito Only reference to R1 is this. "The resistor R1 acts as a pull-up resistor for pin 2."

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This does not look like a great design missing so many details such as the light beam interruption and how stray light is blocked is very important.

You have an obligation to show what values you used and what layout and voltage vs light measurements. Then actually explain your problem with a question!

So I decided to simulate **[here on Falstad](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+2+0.000005+5.023272298708815+64+7+50%0Aa+288+168+384+168+9+5+0+1000000+5+1.6666666666666665+100000%0Aa+288+264+384+264+9+5+0+1000000+3.333333333333333+3.3314794215795334+100000%0Ar+240+56+240+104+0+5000%0Ar+240+104+240+152+0+5000%0Aw+240+152+240+176+2%0Ar+240+176+240+264+0+5000%0Aw+240+152+288+152+0%0Aw+216+104+240+104+0%0Aw+216+104+216+280+0%0Aw+272+280+288+280+0%0Aw+464+176+464+192+0%0Aw+384+184+384+192+0%0Aw+384+192+464+240+0%0Aw+464+240+464+256+0%0Aw+384+240+384+248+0%0Aw+384+240+464+192+0%0AR+240+32+240+-8+0+0+40+5+0+0+0.5%0Ar+88+32+88+184+0+30000%0Aw+136+352+216+352+0%0Aw+560+272+600+272+0%0Aw+88+184+88+248+0%0Ag+56+312+56+328+0%0Ar+384+368+464+368+0+10000%0Aw+464+176+496+176+0%0Aw+464+368+496+368+0%0A153+384+256+464+256+1+2+1.8214596497756476e-20+5%0A153+384+176+464+176+1+2+5+5%0Aw+496+176+496+368+0%0AO+528+256+536+288+0%0Aw+144+184+192+184+2%0Aw+88+248+288+248+2%0At+328+368+296+368+0+1+0.5738649752086677+0.5917932270308583+100%0Aw+216+352+296+352+0%0Ag+296+384+296+408+0%0Aw+328+368+384+368+0%0Ax+149+343+218+346+4+16+discharge%0Ax+106+178+151+181+4+16+trigger%0Ax+103+239+168+242+4+16+threshold%0Aw+136+280+216+280+2%0Ax+110+273+158+276+4+16+control%0Ab+513+398+199+40+0%0Aw+240+264+240+384+0%0Aw+240+384+296+384+0%0Aw+240+32+144+32+0%0Aw+240+56+240+32+0%0Aw+216+280+272+280+0%0A174+88+248+56+376+1+100000+0.5990000000000001+Resistance%0Aw+464+256+528+256+0%0Ar+560+32+560+184+0+1000%0A162+560+184+560+240+2+default-led+1+0+0+0.01%0Aw+240+32+560+32+0%0AS+528+256+560+256+0+0+false+0+2%0AM+384+168+384+144+0+2.5%0AM+384+264+384+296+0+2.5%0Aw+192+184+288+184+0%0Ar+144+184+144+32+0+100000%0Aw+144+32+88+32+0%0Aw+192+184+192+-24+0%0Aw+192+-24+600+-24+0%0Aw+600+-24+600+272+0%0Ao+28+32+0+4106+0.0000762939453125+0.00009765625+0+1%0A)**

[image]

On this, if you simulate a slight loss of light by sliding the pot to the right the LED goes ON ( Alarm ) and latches with Trig Pulled up on pin 2 . Almost any value works for Trig pullup,  1k to 1M

Then you can click on my SPDT switch to reset the alarm. Then slide pot back to left to simulate light detected and repeat.

The R2 value determines your threshold of detection, with the Control Reference exactly 2/3 of Vcc.

Edit 5:06 pm
Now seeing your values, looks like R2 is far too low and requires a lot of light to trigger.  Increase it until you trigger then back off a bit just to simulate loss of light beam.

Comment: Resistance of photocell is 165 ohm when laser is hitting it.

Comment: What is the "Threshold" voltage for each state? and Vcc

Comment: Resistance of photo cell is 165 ohms.

Comment: Resistance is 24.6 from the 200K scale. I am confused as to what that value that is. @Sunnyskyguy EE75

Comment: What is Vcc?  ...your supply voltage

Comment: @ Sunnyskyguy EE75 9 volt dc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93246/discussion-between-fixit7-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Comment: I did some experimenting with the resistance of the photo cell.

Photocell 400mW 350V pack 8K ohm Max Light 1M ohm in. Dark

At about 6 inches from the laser, it's about 165 ohms.

At 18 feet, it is around 160 ohms.
(I turned on a 60 watt light, but it did not appreciably change the resistance.)

In darkness, it is about 24,600 ohms.

Comment: OK . Lots of margin between On and Off .   I allow 50% loss margin over time with the laser so 160 may double to 320 so the R2 needs to be just greater than this for the alarm to trip reliably  over some time.    Laser diodes dont last as long if over driven ..

Comment: R2 needs to be raised to about the value of your interference light. In this case I'd suggest that it should be 15-20k Ohm. If you put a low value resistor then the current flowing with the Laser on the CDS is very high ...it does not need to be. If you set it at 100 Ohms, your current is about 45mA ...if you set it at 320 Ohms it will be about 21mA ….both needlessly high.

Comment: Yes if using a battery, Laser's and LDR's are a poor solution, Then using 15-20k results in a power saving but poor response time from LDR capacitance. so trip time will be increased by factor of a hundred from the 1ms. Laser diodes take a lot more power than this detector so if using batteries. this is also a problem. But if power is not a problem with AC or a battery trickle charge then 21 mA is not an issue.

Comment: But because the OP has no electronic background, and the circuit was just some DIY solution, there are more issues than meets the eye. Not difficult, just unspecified.

Comment: I plan on using a 9 volt power adaptor. No batteries. Laser also has its own power adaptor.

Comment: I got the ne 555p chip.   

I looked at the data sheet for this ne 555p chip. I can not figure out where the pin locations are.?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fitler9s3jt0i64/NE555P.jpg?dl=0

As in where is pin #1 in this picture? I could not find a way to include the pic in this comment.

Comment: Datasheet shows everything. dot for pin 1

Answer (score 0):

I used a 2 inch piece of 3/4 inch pvc pipe to shroud the photo cell.

It reduced the amount of background light enough to where the circuit works.

[image]